# Grouped list with embed expander

Tags: xamarin.forms

I recently started to learn Xamarin and am now trying to find a solution for my project. I have a code in HAML and I can fill my order with dishes with ingredients. Dishes with ingredients are an expander, and I want to add a grouping by guests. Guests can be 1, 2 or more, and each has its own set of dishes. I tried to use CollectionView to group, but there is an error on UWP --- GitHub # 10890.

Maybe I should create my order in code, but I don’t understand how to make bindings to the Expander (((

I need one more grouping: “guest 1”, “guest 2”, etc. In one order there are several guests and each has his own list, and I also need to add a dish to the list of a particular guest when adding.

[I need a structure (image):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoIbP.png)

**Guest 1**
    Dish 1
       *Ingredient 1

       Ingredient 2*

**Guest 2**
    Dish 1
       *Ingredient 1

       Ingredient 2

       Ingredient 3*
    Dish 2 *(no ingredients)*
    Dish 3
       *Ingredient 1

       Ingredient 2*

**My XAML without groups:**

```
            <ScrollView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="25" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">

                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" WidthRequest="3" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                <syncfusion:SfExpander Grid.Column="1" >
                                    <syncfusion:SfExpander.Header>
                                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F2F4F8" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </syncfusion:SfExpander.Header>
                                    <syncfusion:SfExpander.Content>
                                      <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F2F4F8" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="10">
                                            <Label Text="Ingredients" TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.5" FontSize="10" Margin="20,0"/>
                                            <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0,0,20">
                                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Label TextColor="#2F3246" FontSize="12">
                                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                                <FormattedString>
                                                                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                        <Span Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                </FormattedString>
                                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                                        </Label>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid></syncfusion:SfExpander.Content>
                                </syncfusion:SfExpander>
                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>



            <!--Order Test-->
```

**I tried to do this in code, it works and gives me the desired grouping, but I don’t understand how to implement PropertyChanged**

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="OrderGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="25" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
</Grid>
```

CODE:

```
            scrollView = new ScrollView();
            stack = new StackLayout();  

            var List = new OrderPageViewModel();
            OrderList = List.Items;            

            if (OrderList != null)
                foreach (var shoppingItem in OrderList)
                {
                    expander = new Expander();
                    //Expander Header
                    var headergrid = new Grid()
                    {
                        HeightRequest = 60
                    };
                    var headerLabel = new Label()
                    {
                        TextColor = Color.White,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Teal,
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        Text = shoppingItem.Name,
                        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                    };
                    headergrid.Children.Add(headerLabel);
                    expander.Header = headergrid;

                    var contentgrid = new Grid();
                    var stackExpanderContent = new StackLayout();

                    foreach (var shoppingDetailItem in shoppingItem.Items)
                    {
                        //Expander Content
                        var contentLabel = new Label()
                        {
                            TextColor = Color.Black,
                            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                            Text = shoppingDetailItem.Name,
                            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                            HeightRequest = 50
                        };
                        stackExpanderContent.Children.Add(contentLabel);
                    }

                    contentgrid.Children.Add(stackExpanderContent);
                    expander.Content = contentgrid;
                    stack.Children.Add(expander);
                }

            scrollView.Content = stack;
            scrollView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
            OrderGrid.Children.Add(scrollView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reconstruct your xaml and model class .

It is a bit complex than the  original one .

#### Xaml

```
<ScrollView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="25" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">

            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackLayout>

                        <Label Text="{Binding ID}"  TextColor="Red" FontSize="12"/>

                        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">

                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">


                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="3" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        <syncfusion:SfExpander Grid.Column="1" >
                                            <syncfusion:SfExpander.Header>
                                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F2F4F8" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20">
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </syncfusion:SfExpander.Header>
                                            <syncfusion:SfExpander.Content>
                                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F2F4F8" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="10">
                                                        <Label Text="Ingredients" TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.5" FontSize="10" Margin="20,0"/>
                                                        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0,0,20">
                                                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <Label TextColor="#2F3246" FontSize="12">
                                                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                                                            <FormattedString>
                                                                                <FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                                    <Span Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                                                </FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                            </FormattedString>
                                                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                                                    </Label>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </syncfusion:SfExpander.Content>
                                        </syncfusion:SfExpander>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>

            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

#### Code hebind

```
 public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Guest
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public List<Model> Items { get; set; }
    }


    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Guest> Items { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Items = new List<Guest>();


            Model model = new Model { Name = "Cole", Items = new List<Item> { new Item { Name = "aa" }, new Item { Name = "bb" } } };
            Model model2 = new Model { Name = "Tom", Items = new List<Item> { new Item { Name = "cc" }, new Item { Name = "dd" } } };
            Model model3 = new Model { Name = "Kevin", Items = new List<Item> { new Item { Name = "ee" }} };

            Items.Add(new Guest { ID = "Guest 1", Items = new List<Model> { model } });
            Items.Add(new Guest { ID = "Guest 2", Items = new List<Model> { model2 ,model3} });

            this.BindingContext = this;

        }

    }
```

#### Test result

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works for me too, but I need one more grouping: “guest 1”, “guest 2”, etc. In one order there are several guests and each has his own list, and I also need to add a dish to the list of a particular guest when adding.

Guest 1  <br/>  
    Dish 1<br/>  
       Ingredient 1<br/>   
       Ingredient 2<br/>       
  
Guest 2<br/> 
    Dish 1<br/>  
       Ingredient 1<br/>    
       Ingredient 2<br/>  
       Ingredient 3<br/>  
    Dish 2 (no ingredients)<br/>  
    Dish 3<br/>  
       Ingredient 1<br/>   
       Ingredient 2<br/>

Comment: It works, thank you very much, this is what you need)))